# Error in loop reading multiple text files

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, connection

I'm a bit stuck with this code... The purpose is to read only text files from a folder with few different kind of files, take a column for each one and create a data frame with every extracted column (`cbind.fill` is a hand-made function that add a new column and fill the "empty" spaces with NA values). Here is the code:

```
setwd("...folderOfInterest/")
genes_data <- data.frame()
for(i in list.files(pattern = "^GO_.*txt", full.names = TRUE)){
  print(i) #this works perfectly, it only prints desired files...
  q <- read.table(i, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = NULL)
  genes_data <- cbind.fill(genes_data, q[,2])
}
```

As @Adam B suggests, here is the `print(i)` output and a screenshot of the folder ([folder_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYTVH.png)):

```
[1] "./GO_ALPHA_AMINO_ACID_CATABOLIC_PROCESS.xls"
[1] "./GO_ALPHA_AMINO_ACID_METABOLIC_PROCESS.xls"
[1] "./GO_ALPHA_BETA_T_CELL_ACTIVATION.xls"
[1] "./GO_AMINO_ACID_BETAINE_METABOLIC_PROCESS.xls"
[1] "./GO_AMINO_ACID_IMPORT.xls"
[1] "./GO_AMINO_ACID_TRANSMEMBRANE_TRANSPORT.xls"
[1] "./GO_AMINO_ACID_TRANSPORT.xls"
[1] "./GO_AMINOGLYCAN_BIOSYNTHETIC_PROCESS.xls"
[1] "./GO_ANGIOGENESIS.xls"
[1] "./GO_ANION_TRANSPORT.xls"
[1] "./GO_ANTIGEN_PROCESSING_AND_PRESENTATION.xls"
[1] "./GO_ANTIGEN_PROCESSING_AND_PRESENTATION_OF_ENDOGENOUS_ANTIGEN.xls"
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file './GO_ANTIGEN_PROCESSING_AND_PRESENTATION_OF_ENDOGENOUS_ANTIGEN.xls': No such file or directory
```

(note: the files' extension is .xls, but really they are .txt files)

It propmts this message:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file './GO_ANTIGEN_PROCESSING_AND_PRESENTATION.txt': No such file or directory
```

Also running only `q <- read.table(i, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = NULL)` appears this error message.

I think I'm in the correct folder (because `print(i)` works good), I've also changed `full.names` option and set `list.files` as a variable out the loop... but nothins seems to work. Please, if anybody has an idea it'll be welcome!

Comment: Try changing your read table line to: `q <- read.table(i[1], header = TRUE, sep = "\t", quote = NULL)`

Comment: Thanks @Mako212, but the error persists...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it on randomly generated files and it works. You probably do not need to cd into the directory with the data, just give the `list.files` a `dir` argument with the path to your data directory.

```
GOfls <- list.files("indata", pattern = "^GO_.*\\.txt", full.names = TRUE)
head(GOfls)
[1] "indata/GO_amswylfbgp.txt" "indata/GO_amswylfbgptxt"  "indata/GO_apqqqktvir.txt"
[4] "indata/GO_arwudmbzsr.txt" "indata/GO_autljyljgn.txt" "indata/GO_beeqcmnayk.txt"
# lapply -> do.call for reading and binding the data is better approach
gene_data <- do.call('cbind', lapply(GOfls, function(path) read.delim(path)[,2]))
# have a look at the data
dim(gene_data)
[1] 100 100
```

I have tried to reproduce your problem this way (it's optional text):

```
dir.create("indata")
fls <- lapply(1:100, function(i) data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 10)))
names(fls) <- replicate(100, paste0("./indata/", "GO_", 
                                    paste0(sample(letters, 10, replace = T), 
                                           collapse = ""), ".txt"
                                    )
                        )
lapply(names(fls), function(x) write.table(fls[[x]], x, quote = F, sep = "\t"))
head(dir("indata"))
[1] "GO_acebruujkw.pdf" "GO_amswylfbgp.txt" "GO_amswylfbgptxt" "GO_apqqqktvir.txt"
[5] "GO_arwudmbzsr.txt" "GO_autljyljgn.txt"
# I have added some renamed .txt files (.pdf, .tiff, .gel) to the indata
rm(list = ls())
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @utubun. Finally I solved the problem (see below)!

Answer (score 0):

That's solved! It's a bit strange but copying the folder of interest into the desktop the code seems to work again.

A mate and I saw that hard disk's activity was collapsed, so we thought that maybe there could be a problem in the process of reading... so copying the folder was the (simple) solution!

Nevertheless, if anybody has an idea that explains this strange situation I'm sure it'll be useful! Thanks a lot!

EDIT

I've done some tests and maybe the problem is the name of the folder path, which it'd too long and crashes the loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you're searching for .xls files, but then trying to open it at as a .txt file

In excel try saving the files as comma or tab delimited text files.

If you want to open excel files directly they have a few packages that can do that. Try readxl.

Comment: No, sorry, it was a mistake... it should be .txt not .xls (I've already corrected it).

Comment: Try getting rid of the ^ in list files line. Also can you show us the output of print(i) and a screenshot of the folder in question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Adam B. I'v edited the aswer with your suggestions. The ^ is for an exact match at the begining of the file, it's necessary (and there's no change, I tried also).

Comment: Yes as my original answer suggested. You're trying to open up xls files. Try saving them in excel as tab-delimited text files. Or use specific functions to read excel files. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but this files are really .txt files, I've already tried open them with a xls package and it was impossible (and conversely, I could with `read.table`)

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. How are they text files when they have .xls in the print command?